# Deploying Django on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy Django on EB but here's my issue:

The deployment goes well, and I can migrate and create a superuser from the .config file in the .ebextensions directory.
The only thing is, the Django server doesn't start by itself, and I have to `python manage.py runserver` via SSH to get it working. Which brings up another issue: when the EC2 instance shuts down, the Django server stops too and is not restarted at the next instantiation.

Here's my .config file:

```yaml
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/activate && export $(sudo cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env | xargs) && cd /var/app/staging/my_project_name && python manage.py migrate --noinput"
    leader_only: true

  02_createsu:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/activate && export $(sudo cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env | xargs) && cd /var/app/staging/my_project_name && python manage.py createsu"
    leader_only: true

option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "monga.settings"
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: /var/app/current/my_project_name/my_project_name/wsgi.py
    NumProcesses: 3
    NumThreads: 20
```

I even tried to add the following without success (it cannot even be deployed, probably because it gets stuck with the `runserver` command):

```yaml
  03_runserver:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/activate && export $(sudo cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env | xargs) && cd /var/app/staging/my_project_name && python manage.py runserver"
    leader_only: true
```

What should I do to get the Django server to run automatically?